# cancel Timer out from method

Tags: java, android, timer

I have a problem with canceling this timer out of this method.

```
 public void nezablokovat() {
    int secondsToRun = 9999999;
    final ValueAnimator timern = ValueAnimator.ofInt(secondsToRun);
    timern.setDuration(secondsToRun * 1000).setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
    timern.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
            int elapsedSeconds = (int) animation.getAnimatedValue();
            int minutes = elapsedSeconds / 60;
            int seconds = elapsedSeconds % 60;

            if (seconds%10 == 1) {
                Pis("$$$");
            }
        }

        });
        timern.start();
    }
```

I want to put `timern.cancel();` to an other method in the `onClick` Listener for the Button. 
Please Do you have some ideas?

If I put `timern.cancel()` here:

```
void teplotahore() {
    STup.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    timern.cancel();
                    }
                }
            }

    );
}
```

The compiler doesn't know `timern`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how you're whole class is structured, but I believe you may be able to just move the "timern" "variable" outside the constructor (above it) that way making it a field.

A field is like a variable, however it is visible to all methods in the class.

For example:

```
final ValueAnimator timern = ValueAnimator.ofInt(secondsToRun);

public void nezablokovat() {
    int secondsToRun = 9999999;

    timern.setDuration(secondsToRun * 1000).setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
    timern.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
        int elapsedSeconds = (int) animation.getAnimatedValue();
        int minutes = elapsedSeconds / 60;
        int seconds = elapsedSeconds % 60;

        if (seconds%10 == 1) {
            Pis("$$$");
        }


    }

    });
    timern.start();
}

void teplotahore() {
    STup.setOnClickListener(
        new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                timern.cancel();
            }
        }

    });
}
```